# Awfuly Formatted LaTeX Table, How can I improve it

Tags: latex, pdflatex

Its pretty much my first time using LaTeX and I'm trying to add a table with bunch of information and Text. Why are there a bunch of whitespaces in between some words. Is there a way to improve it or is my approach complety wrong. I take any advice

[image]

```
  \begin{table}[h]
    \raggedbottom
    \caption{Ziele SMART formulieren}
    \label{crouch}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{4.6cm}|p{4.6cm}|p{4.6cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Ziele} & \textbf{Wirtschaftlichkeit} & \textbf{Prozessqualität} & \textbf{Verfügbarkeit} \\
        \hline
        Zielbeschreibung & Im nächsten Geschäftsjahr (2024) IT-Betriebskosten um 15 Prozent senken \newline Basis: 2023 & Die Kundenzufriedenheit im IT-Service-Desk-Bereich durchschnittlich um 20 Prozent innerhalb der nächsten sechs Monate steigern \newline Basis: Aktueller Stand & Die Verfügbarkeit der kritischen IT-Services auf 99.9 Prozent bis zum Ende des Jahres erhöhen \newline Basis: Aktueller Stand \\
        \hline
        Spezifisch & Reduzierung der IT-Betriebskosten um 15 Prozent & Steigerung der Kundenzufriedenheit um 20 Prozent & Erhöhung der Verfügbarkeit auf 99.9 Prozent \\
        \hline
        Messbar & Finanzberichte vergleichen & Durch Umfragen und Feedbackmessungen messbar & Durch Überwachung und Ausfallzeitmessungen \\
        \hline
        Attraktiv & Steigerung der Rentabilität & Verbesserung der Servicequalität & Sicherung der Geschäftskontinuität \\
        \hline
        Realistisch & Durch Kosteneinsparungen und Effizienzverbesserungen realistisch & Durch Schulung und Prozessoptimierung realistisch & Durch die Implementierung bewährter Verfügbarkeitsmaßnahmen realistisch \\
        \hline
        Termiernierbar & Bis Ende des nächsten Geschäftsjahres & Innerhalb der nächsten sechs Monate & Innerhalb des nächsten Jahres \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you can adopt the solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/198327 to apply `\raggedright` to the cells in the table.

Namely, add a new column type in your preamble:

```tex
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
```

(I changed `m{#1}` to `p{#1}` in the original solution.)

Then, change the tabular columns as

```tex
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|L{4.6cm}|L{4.6cm}|L{4.6cm}|}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not already doing so then use the [babel](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel/) package to change the hyphenation rules to German. You can also give hyphenation hints by use of `\-`, which tells LaTeX that a word can be broken at that point if need be. You can do this instead of or as well as using the babel package (though it'll be considerably less work to use the babel package such that you only need to deal with cases that it can't handle)

For example `Kunden\-zufrieden\-heit` (in row 2 column 3)